# Regex to stop at the first occurrence of #STRING# inside the regex

Tags: php, regex

*Note: The output of the Array() is a PHP print_r()*

I have this HTML tag:

```
<tr>
    <td width="40" align="left"><div class="icSkill" id="skill4"></div></td>
    <td colspan="2">SOME_VALUE_I_WANT&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I really want to extract this with RegEx and don't want to use HTML parsers in this case.

I do this Regex (I use the s-flag to ignore the file's newlines):

```
\<tr\>\<td\swidth="40"\salign="left"\>\<div\s+class="icSkill"\s+id="skill(\d+)".*\<\/tr\>
```

Problem now is that the Regex doesn't stop at the first found close TR tag, but I want it to. I know it probably has something todo with assertions, only I don't know how to.

```
Array
(
    [0] => <tr><td width="40" align="left"><div class="icSkill" id="skill4"></div></td><td colspan="2">SOME_VALUE_I_WANT&nbsp;
</td></tr><tr><td rowspan="2" align="left"><div class="icGuard" id="guard9"></div></td></tr>
    [1] => 4
)
```

The basic examples like: /[^<]*/ won't work in this case. Is there also a way to tell regex something like:

```
/[^A_STRING]*/ (in words; stop unless you find A_STRING)
OR BETTER EXAMPLE:
/[^A_STRING_FIRST_TIME]*/ (in words; stop unless you find A_STRING for the FIRST_TIME)
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use an HTML parser in this case?

Comment: Where is your code ? We can't see the modifiers you are using. Most likely you are missing the `U` modifier. Besides, make yourself to want using html parsers (aka domdocument)

Comment: Maybe I should've asked the question differently, sorry. I just want to know if I can do \[^a]\ where "a" would be a string. Don't want this \[^abc]\, because it allows the characters all to be valid exceptions.

Comment: @Alex: I'm using the global and dotall flags.

Comment: Also, why are you escaping angle brackets?

Comment: @Allendar PHP doesn't have a global flag. Globalness is determined by the function you use.

Comment: @m.buettner: I use preg_match_all().

Comment: @Allendar then using this function is enough to make the search global. no need to use `g` (because it simply doesn't exist in PHP)

Comment: @RohitJain: this seems to work in this case, thank you.

Comment: @m.buettner: Yes sorry my bad. I only do /REGEX/s in the preg_match_all(). I was just noting it because it's set as active in the tool I test my Regex in :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy). `.*` consumes as much as it can. You can make it ungreedy by appending `?`:

```
~<tr><td\s+width="40"\s+align="left"><div\s+class="icSkill"\s+id="skill(\d+)".*?</tr>~s
```

Also, as you can see, there is really no need to do so much escaping. It only hinders legibility.

An alternative way to make repetition ungreedy, is to use the modifier `U`, which makes all repetition ungreedy globally in the whole pattern. I prefer the local variant (using `?`), though.

In any case, there is a different possibility which mimics `[^A_STRING]*` (which doesn't work, because it matches any string of characters, that do not include `A`, `_`, `S`, `T`, `R`, `I`, `N` or `G`). You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) at every position of the repetition:

```
(?:(?!A_STRING).)*
```

(substitute this for `.*` or `.*?`). It should be equivalent in most cases, but execution time might differ. Plus, it's a little harder to decipher.

Comment: Thanks, really great! I mostly wanted to know "string"-matching for the future too. Concerning the over exaggerated escaping; I'm trying to keep to the illegal characters on the cheat-sheet I use from AddedBytes.com. It states Metacharacters that must be escaped: ^[.${*(\+)|?<> Yet somehow PHP sometimes seems to choke if I don't escape the forward slash (/).
Once again my thanks ^^

Comment: @Allendar `/` only needs to be escaped if you use `/` as your delimiter. Hence, never escape `/`. Instead, look for a delimiter character that is not part of your regex. For ther others. I agree with all of these, but `<>` are only meta-characters if used like `(?<name>...` or `(?P<name>...`. So you can usually leave them unescaped, too. Regular expressions are usually tough to read anyway, so I would go for reducing clutter by escaping as much as possible. (Also in character classes, you only need to escape `^`, `]`, `\ ` and `-` - just FYI)

Comment: Thanks M, this really helps me a lot! I'm did some Regex in the past, but every time I pick it up again I feel like I have to relearn it, haha.

Comment: @Allendar the page I've linked twice is a very good read to actually properly get your head around regular expressions, so you will have to relearn less of it next time you need to use them: [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: That lazy match saved my life. I started to learn lookahead and lookbehind matches when my regex just needed was a lazy match `*?` instead of a greedy match `*`

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough one. Usually you'd have a class identifier in there which would make it easier.

So let's make sure that I understand what you want: You need to capture whatever is within the last `<td>` tag, just before we close the table row. In that case, you need a negative lookahead:

`<td(?!.*?<td).*?>(.*?)<\/td>`

This, together with the `s` modifier, will capture `SOME_VALUE_I_WANT&nbsp;`, provided it is in the last `<td>` element in the table row.

The only element in this regex which is not straightforward is the negative lookahead operator `<td(?!.*?<td)`, which will capture only a `<td>` element that is not followed by another such element.

Also, when you use the star operator, you usually want to make sure that you modify it to be non-greedy as follows: `(.*?)`. This means it stops at the first match.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth description Nitay. This makes things very clear ^^

Comment: Won't that get the very last `<td>` in the input, regardless of which `<tr>` it is in?

Comment: @m.buettner Yes. It's not exactly clear from the OP what are the exact characteristics of the pattern he is trying to match. That's the way I understood it. Anyway, parsing HTML with regexes is probably not something we should do very often, they're too obtuse for this purpose.

Comment: agreed. there is a reason for for [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) ;)